# CheckBox partly visible

Tags: android, checkbox, size

I am using a `CheckBox` in my layout which is partly visible.I am including the screenshot.

Below is the layout and java code.

**xml:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox

                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text="Check box"
                    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
                    android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

**java:**

```
checkbox=(AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

               if(isChecked){
                   relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               }
                else {
                   relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }
            }
        });
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: change         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` are **too small,** change them to `"wrap_content"`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Check box"
     android:id="@+id/checkbox"
     android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
     android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that OnCheckedChangeListener is called one time when you run applicatiom.
Then, try to set different size. Maybe 20dp is too small.